# Facebook Enhanced Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook

The new enhanced auth dialog also shows which of your friends are also using the app. Is there any way to hide this? There are certain apps for which it would be more politically correct to NOT know who else is using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try disabling `Social Discovery` in the apps settings. 
Also you could try setting the `Default Activity Privacy` to "Only me".

Comment: I don't think suggestion #1 applies since it's not a canvas app (it's just used for website login). I set the privacy default to "Only me", so hopefully that works.